# Problema al actualizar label tkinter dentro de ciclo for

Tags: python, tkinter

Debo hacer algo como un cronometro, tengo la función para este

```
def cronometro2():
    btnIniciaCrono.pack_forget()
    ahora = time.time()
    for h in range(0, 24):
        for m in range(0, 60):
            for s in range(0, 60):
                prevCrono = h, ":", m, ":", s
                crono.set(prevCrono)
                time.sleep(1)
```

que, como se ve, hace un `set` a la  `tkinter.StringVar`, que se crea mas adelante

```
btnIniciaCrono = tkinter.Button(frBienvenido, text="Iniciar", command=cronometro2)
crono = tkinter.StringVar()
crono.set("00:00:00")
tkinter.Label(frBienvenido, textvariable=crono, fg="yellow", bg="black", font=("", 30)).place(relx=0.5, y=230, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)
```

pero al momento de hacer click en el boton, cuando deberia empezar a actualizar el `label`, solo se queda congelada la ventana, probablemente el problema esté en la forma de usar el `set`, desconozco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás haciendo `time.sleep()` y estás matando el loop que actualiza tu GUI (va a esperar 1x24x60x60 segundos, hasta que acabe el temporizador). Si usas `threading`, la función se va a ejecutar en un hilo, paralelamente al loop de `tkinter`, lo que te permitirá seguir trabajando con la ventana mientras el cronómetro se sigue actualizando.

```
import threading

def cronometro2():
    btnIniciaCrono.pack_forget()
    ahora = time.time()
    def proceso_crono():
        for h in range(0, 24):
            for m in range(0, 60):
                for s in range(0, 60):
                    prevCrono = h, ":", m, ":", s
                    crono.set(prevCrono)
                    time.sleep(1)
    th = threading.Thread(target=proceso_crono)
    th.start()
```

PD: Tal vez quieras rellenar con cero a la izquierda tu temporizador ;)

```
prevCrono = str(h).zfill(2), ":", str(m).zfill(2), ":", str(s).zfill(2)
```

Comment: ¿Crees que la mejor opción para poder ver el mismo cronometro en otros frames sea poniéndolo en un frame especifico mas pequeño?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo de ponerlo en un frame específico más pequeño... Si quieres que se vea igual en más de una ventana, puedes simplemente hacer Labels que compartan el mismo StringVar

Comment: Tus comentarios me han sido de gran ayuda, pero ahora tengo la duda sobre si hay alguna forma de pausar el hilo, para así pausar el cronometro, luego continuar y así. He buscado y al parecer no la hay, pero quizás busqué mal.

Comment: si estás haciendo programación orientada a objetos, puedes guardar el thread como un atributo y creo que con `th.terminate()`bastaría... sino, creeeo que tendrías que usar variables globales, puedes hacer otra pregunta si necesitas más ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar colocando un update en el frame después de crono.set() ya que debe refrescar la pagina para que muestre el contenido durante la misma función, siendo algo así:

```
def cronometro2():
    btnIniciaCrono.pack_forget()
    ahora = time.ctime()#aqui para que muestre la hora actual debe ser ctime
    for h in range(0, 24):
        for m in range(0, 60):
            for s in range(0, 60):
                prevCrono = h, ":", m, ":", s
                crono.set(prevCrono)
                frBienvenido.update()#refresca el frame en este punto
                time.sleep(1)
```